# Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for an index segment in the tablespace indicated

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, alter

i tried to run a stored procedure as follows,

```
insert into process_state_archive select * from process_state 
where tstamp BETWEEN trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)) AND trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3))
```

Got below error :

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01654: Kan index WEBDEV.PROCESS_STAT_TSTAMP_ACTION niet uitbreiden met 8 in     tabelruimte USERS.
01654. 00000 -  "unable to extend index %s.%s by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
       an index segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
       files to the tablespace indicated.
```

But Yesterday i could able to run the procedure without any error.

Can any one please tell me the resolution for the above error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `USERS` tablespace is full. You may be able to free up some space by dropping something, possibly old objects - if this is a development environment in particular, see if you've been accumulating old objects in [the recycle bin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/tables011.htm) and purge any you no longer require.

If you can't fee up any space then you need to do what the error message tells you to do, add an additional data file to the tablespace, or increase the size of an existing data file, assuming you have sufficient disk space to do so.

The documentation [has a section about managing data files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dfiles.htm#ADMIN11421), including [adding data files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dfiles.htm#ADMIN11422) and [changing the size of existing data files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dfiles.htm#ADMIN11423). Which action is appropriate will depend on your circumstances, and you'll need to decide what size is appropriate. You might also want to consider creating a new dedicated tablespace for your application rather than using the `USERS` tablespace, but again depends on your circumstances and needs.